# Public API to Gather Facebook Check-ins by Location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I hate to just ask a question like this, but the StackOverflow community is just so freaking responsive... I can't resist...

We all know about FourSquare and their API. You can search for checkins by location because foursuare is pretty public. My question is, is there any similar API available for Facebook where I can see anonymous checkin data by location? Checkins/post locations/etc.

I am leaning towards "no", but I thought I'd ping the crowd first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is not available since any checkin object requires the respective permissions to read it.So even if you somehow got a bunch of Checkin object ids...you would be unable to retrieve any of the detailed data about them.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/